# apache airflow 2.0.2 slow web UI

Tags: amazon-ec2, airflow, gunicorn

I have installed apache-airflow 2.0 on a new EC2 instance (r5a.xlarge) 4 CPU and 32 RAM and SSD disk.
Airflow webserver and scheduler are running in a stable way, BUT the web response is slooooow even with 0 DAGs in execution.
The instance lives in N.Virginia as well as the postgres database (AURORA RDS)is running there.

Since the web responsive is slow (~5 seconds for a web page to load) I tried to scale the amount of workers to 7 but seems to be such change dit not helped as expected.

Literally when one do click on whatever link i.e Admin Variables link, the browser has to wait until 5 seconds to receive a response from http://ec2-#-###-###-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/variable/list/

I would like to listen suggestions from you guys,
so guys, is there any thing that I am missing?
does exist the possibility of split the webserver and scheduler on different instances?
is it just a problem with the UI apart from scheduler and executors?

thanks a lot for any tip, suggestion or fix!

Comment: May not be worth much but I donot see airflow certified on aurora backed DBs 
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html

Can you try using a simple RDS postgres instance??

Comment: Sometimes, the issue could also be the DNS. Have you tried using the IP address in your URL instead of the DNS?

Comment: If this is not a DNS problem, it could be an MTU issue if there is "something" between you and the server (firewall or tunnel). Try to remove path MTU discovery and set the MTU to a small value like 576 (the minimum MTU for an IPv4 packet).

Comment: I tried this, but on a t2.micro instance. Was thinking, heh maybe 1 vCPU + 1 GB RAM is just not enough for Airflow. But I have the same problem - the Airflow components are running, but web response is extremely slow. Besides that, t2.micro is really not enough, I have about 86% avg. CPU utilization with it

Answer (score 1):

1. Try checking the airflow-webserver logs , verify if there are any frequent Gunicorn worker timeouts .
2. Airflow webserver has to load all the UI components( dags , tasks , status etc) by querying the airflow meta database . Check the CPU utilisation and the number of active connections to the airlfow-meta database which you configured . I faced a similar issue where the web UI was too slow and clicking on anything would take lot of time to load. I noticed that the mysql RDS instance which I was using as the meta DB , was hitting 99.8% CPU utilisation continuously ( I was using the same RDS for other applications also ) . Upon upgrading the RDS instance , the issue was resolved .